# How to exclude "0" from the output when the user enters it?

Tags: python, arrays, input

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Read input names from user until 0, print input
inputNames = []
names = ""
while names != "0":
    names = input("Please enter a name or enter '0' to quit: ")
    inputNames.append(names)
    if names == "0":
        del inputNames[3]
print("\n".join(inputNames))
```

This was just a quick fix, because I can't figure out how to exclude "0" from the output when the user enters "0" to print the list.  So it should input names to the array until "0" is entered, then print the array in order of input on each line minus the "0" input.  Mine works as long as there are only 3 names entered.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - what is your *question*? What happened when you tried to run the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: When the user enters in the `0` it's going to display on the screen because that's how `input()` works. If you want to delete the last element in the list, use `del inputNames[-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put "inputNames.pop()" or "inputNames.remove('0')" after the while loop to remove the zero.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to something I hadn't thought of, using remove!

Comment: # Read input names from user until 0, print input

inputNames = []

names = ""

while names != "0":
    
    names = input("Please enter a name or enter '0' to quit: ")
    
    inputNames.append(names)

    if names == "0":
        inputNames.remove("0")
        

print("\n".join(inputNames))

Comment: also, you dont need "if names == 0:" because the while loop is already set to end if names is equal to zero. and then you can just remove 0 from the list outside the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Check for 0 BEFORE adding to the list:

```
inputNames = []
while 1:
    name = input("Please enter a name or enter '0' to quit: ")
    if name == '0':
        break
    inputNames.append(name)
print('\n'.join(inputNames))
```